# Sketchup not locking on axis

Tags: sketchup

When using the move tool, I can press `up_arrow` to lock on blue axis, `right_arrow` to lock on red axis, but although the documentation claims `left_arrow` locks to green axis it instead orbits the start point moving through the red and blue axis.

Blue axis lock:
[image: blue axis lock]

Red axis lock:
[image: red axis lock]

Green axis not locking but orbiting for some reason:
[image: green axis not lock]

How can I make it stop orbiting and lock to green axis?